MAUI - Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException statemismatcherror on Android 14
My app is currently experiencing login issues on Android 14 (released oct 23) devices.
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: Returned state(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) from authorize endpoint is not the same as the one sent(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx). See https://aka.ms/msal-statemismatcherror for more details. Below is the code I use:
                return await PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(PlatformConfig.Instance.ParentWindow)
                                    .ExecuteAsync()
                                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

I read that using embedded web view true mitigates this issue but I still get the mismatch error.
I have tried to toggle the WithUseEmbeddedWebView but doesn't change the outcome. The app opens the microsoft b2c login page with the embedded browser, the user authenticates but the app shows a blank screen and the user cannot proceed.
Previous android versions are unaffected.

Not sure if the mismatch error is a red herring. Finally found a GitHub post experiencing the same issues https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/4377#issuecomment-1765474934
